# Replacing vulgar fraction in a string to a simple fraction text 1/3

Tags: c#

I am extracting data from Discogs API, from the format section the string that is dumped via browser is:

```
33 ⅓ RPM
```

However when I extract get it from the server and put it in a string and read it back in Console it shows a question mark rather than the vulgar fraction ⅓.

```
33 ? RPM
```

If I do;

```
if (format.Contains("\u2153")
```

it shows true, but this doesn't work:

```
if (format.Contains("\u2153")) format.Replace("\u2153", "1/3");
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong? I read it in byte format and it shows byte 63 for the question mark, but when I check if it contains a question mark it reads false. Also is it possible to display the vulgar fraction?

Comment: You could try using a font that contains the `1/3` character (unlike the Stackoverflow code/comment font)

Comment: Seeing a `?` in text, is a classic case of converting a character into an encoding which doesn't support it.

Answer (score 2):

The [`String.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-6.0#system-string-replace(system-string-system-string)) method returns the modified string and you have to assign that like

```
if (format.Contains("\u2153")) 
  format = format.Replace("\u2153", "1/3");
```

Comment: This is why you shouldn't work on something all day, you make the stupidest mistakes. Thanks man!